# How do I update MongoDB query results using inner query?

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

**BACKGROUND**

I have a collection of json documents that represent chemical compounds. A compound will have an id and a name. An external process generates new compound documents at intervals, and ids may change across iterative generations. Compound documents whose compound ids have changed need to be updated to point to the most recent iterations ids, and as such, a "lastUpdated" field and "relatedCompoundIds" field will be added. To demonstrate, consider the following compounds across 3 steps:

**Step 1**: initial compound document for 'acetone' is generated with id="001".

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "acetone",
    "lastUpdated": "2000-01-01",
}
```

**Step 2**: another iteration generates acetone, but with a different id.

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "acetone",
    "lastUpdated": "2000-01-01"
}
```

```
{
    "id": "002",
    "name": "acetone",
    "lastUpdated": "2000-01-02"
}
```

**Step 3**: compound with id of "001" will append a "relatedCompoundIds" array pointing to any other compounds with the same name.

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "name": "acetone",
    "lastUpdated": "2000-01-02",
    "relatedCompoundIds": ["002"]
}
```

```
{
    "id": "002",
    "name": "acetone",
    "lastUpdated": "2000-01-02"
}
```

I'm using MongoDB to house these records, and to resolve relatedCompoundId "pointers". I'm accessing Mongo using Spring ReactiveMongoTemplate. My process is as follows:

1. Upsert newly generated compounds into MongoDB.
2. For each record where "lastUpdated" is before now:
3. Get all related compounds (searching by name), and set "relatedCompoundIds".

**CODE**

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoOps = new ReactiveMongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(),
                "CompoundStore");

        Date updatedDate = new Date();
        upsertAll(updatedDate, readPath);
        setRelatedCompounds(updatedDate);
    }

    private static void upsertAll(Date updatedDate, String readPath) {
        // [upsertion code here] <- this is working fine
    }

    private static void setRelatedCompounds(Date updatedDate) {
        mongoOps.find(//
                Query.query(Criteria.where("lastUpdated").lt(updatedDate)), Compound.class, "compound")//
                .doOnNext(compound -> {
                    findRelatedCompounds(updatedDate, compound)//
                            .doOnSuccess(rc -> {
                                if (rc.size() > 0) {
                                    compound.setRelatedCompoundIDs(rc);
                                    mongoOps.save(Mono.just(compound)).subscribe();
                                }
                            })//
                            .subscribe();
                }).blockLast();
    }

    private static Mono<List<String>> findRelatedCompounds(Date updatedDate, Compound compound) {
        Query query = new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(//
                Criteria.where("lastUpdated").gte(updatedDate), //
                Criteria.where("name").is(compound.getName)));
        query.fields().include("id");
        return mongoOps.find(query, Compound.class)//
                .map(c -> c.getId())//
                .filter(cid -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(cid))//
                .distinct().collectSortedList();
    }

}
```

**ERROR**

Upon running, I get the following error:

```
17:08:35.957 [Thread-12] ERROR org.mongodb.driver.client - Callback onResult call produced an error
com.mongodb.MongoException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Too many operations are already waiting for a connection. Max number of operations (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many operations are already waiting for a connection. Max number of operations (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.
    at com.mongodb.MongoException.fromThrowableNonNull(MongoException.java:79)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?
How do I adjust backpressure so as not to overload the mongo?
Other advice?

**EDIT**

The above error can be resolved by adding a limitRate modifier after the find method inside setRelatedCompounds.

```
private static void setRelatedCompounds(Date updatedDate) {
    mongoOps.find(//
            Query.query(Criteria.where("lastUpdated").lt(updatedDate)), Compound.class, "compound")//
            .limitRate(500)//
            .doOnNext(compound -> {
                // do work here
                    }).subscribe();
        }).blockLast();
}
```

Still open to suggestions for alternative solutions.

Comment: several questions, why use mongodb, this seems like a relational data structure and is more suited for a relational database. Why keep duplicates in the database, and instead of generating a new item in the db, just update the "lastUpdated" field on the current item (001, Aceton). This solution will scale very, very poorly as because for each new item inserted item you will have to go through the entire database and "update". As the database grows, it will become slower and slower.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Good questsions. Duplicates are kept because the ids are used as url endpoints, and broken links are bad. MongoDB is used because our web pages are static. I don't need to serve dynamic data, but rather resolve links in the documents on some time interval in a batch process, and export said documents to a location on our web server.

Comment: links to id's is fine, but using mongoDB for this is going to punish you in the long run. And your code does not agree with your statement. Since you are running this code in a main method and not in any type of server environment that has a connection pool with multiple connections.